# How to upload a data into share point?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, apache-nifi

Am new to this outlook share point.

i need to upload a file into microsoft sharepoint via REST.

can anyone guide me to do this?

Comment: ok, let me google it for you...

Comment: @tinamou, thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can use CSOM via C# to achieve this, here is a demo for your reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// upload file to Document Library
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="documentLibraryName">MyDocLib</param>
    /// <param name="filePath">C:\\</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">hello2.txt</param>
    public static void uploadFile(ClientContext context, string documentLibraryName, string filePath, string fileName)
    {

        string siteURL = context.Url.EndsWith("/") ? context.Url.Substring(0, context.Url.Length - 1) : context.Url;

        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

        FileCreationInformation newFileInfo = new FileCreationInformation()
        {
            ContentStream = fileStream,
            Url = siteURL + "/" + documentLibraryName + "/" + fileName,
            Overwrite = true
        };

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFileInfo);
        context.Load(file);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

CSOM library download link: [CSOM download](https://chuvash.eu/2014/09/19/export-any-web-part-from-a-sharepoint-page/)

More information about CSOM:
[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

About Rest API, we can refer to the below link:
[REST API in c# to upload document in document Library of sharepoint](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/86f862bb-c05c-44d1-a89d-b61174d5ea1e/rest-api-in-c-to-upload-document-in-document-library-of-sharepoint?forum=appsforsharepoint)

Comment: faced "access to the path is denied"